# Managing EOF in Trx Library

Tags: iso8583

I am using the TRX library to process the ISO8583 Message. I am receiving a Raw data EOF character. But the last byte is not removed from the buffer as it's not defined in the packager and it's causing an issue in parsing the next transaction. How to manage this?

And while sending a response back how to add EOF character?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, this kind of stuff (protocol characters) is removed before decoding ISO8583 data.

For example, you read 100 bytes from the socket. And it's ISO data + EOF character. You would remove EOF character and process 99 bytes of ISO data through a decoder.

And reverse is true when you send data. You encode your data first then add EOF character. The resulting byte array goes into the socket.

Sorry, I don't know anything about TRX library, but, hopefully, general advice helps you somewhat.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I Completely agree with your answer. But I want to know is there any built-in methods in TRX to remove EOF or I can define it in a packager itself